# Dissable the tab bar button but want the enabeled image of disssabled tab bar button

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5, ios6

I am making an tab bar application. I want to disable one tab bar button which I am able to make through the code

`[[[[[self tabBarController] viewControllers] objectAtIndex:2] tabBarItem] setEnabled:FALSE];`

But the image gets disabled. I want the image to be enabled. How it can be possible without using the custom image through code. I do not want to use the custom image of tab bar buttons. I want to use default selected and non selected tab bar button images.Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you could set booleans to know which tab are enabled. And in the delegate `tabBar:didSelectItem:` test those booleans. If the boolean corresponding to the selected tab means this one is not enable, just do a `return;` to exit the delegate.

Comment: @zbMax - But the image changes to non selected image.. I want the selected image even if the tab button is not enabled...

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following: to switch the `UIBarButtonItem` to disabled, instead of switching the property, change [tintColor](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIBarButtonItem/tintColor) property to a clear color. This will prevent the button from being tinted when tapped. Then, in the delegate, check if the button is disabled and return if so:

```
// inside view controller .m

-(void)disableButton
{
    [barBtn setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
}

-(void)enableButton
{
    [barBtn setTintColor:[UIColor grayColor]];  // whatever color the tint should be
}

-(void)buttonTapped:(id)sender
{
    if ([barBtn tintColor] == [UIColor clearColor])
    {
        return;   // button is disabled, so don't to action
    }
}
```

Comment: I neeed to create a category for this??

Comment: @NiKKi No; presumably somewhere in your view controller you have something that causes the button to be enabled / disabled. That calls the `enableButton` / `disableButton` functions. `buttonTapped:`is the callback for the actual tab bar button being tapped. `barBtn` is the `UIBarButtonItem` that is the actual tab bar button. I've slightly modified the code to be clearer